# When click on button copy selected checkboxes

Tags: jquery, button, click, copy, checkboxlist

I am trying to make a function for my application. If you click on a button, I want the value of all selected checkboxes with jQuery to copy to another new empty page. So only the selected checkboxes! The output of the checkboxes comes in a empty HTML page with a div with an ID. The checkbox list with values loads on page by an Ajax XML file. I think I have to make a loop, but I don't know for sure. This is how I started: I'm just a beginner .

```
$('#email').click(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this way :

```
$("#email").click(function(){
   var items = $("input[type=checkbox]").is(":checked");
   $.ajax({
      data: items.serialize()
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's continue the code. We can copy the value of checkbox, and then save it to array.

```
$('#email').click(function(){
    var arr = [];
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
       arr.push($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Now we got the checked checkboxes in array. Lets alert them.

```
alert(arr.toString());
```

Then you said that you want to copy those checked cb-values to another file. That is not so easy, javascript cannot change other files' content. But if you have php on your server, you can use php, and ajax. Let's start. First, jQuery:

```
$('#email').click(function(){
    var arr = [];
    $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
       arr.push($(this).val());
    });
    $.ajax({ // lets post values to php
       type: "POST",
       url: "handler.php",
       data: { arr: JSON.stringify(arr);  } // convert js array to php
    })
    .done(function() {
       alert("Data Saved.");
    });
});
```

Then comes the php bits(handler.php).

```
<?php
   $array = json_decode($_POST['arr'], true);

   echo '<h1>Checked checkboxes</h1><br /><ol>';
   foreach($array as $cb) {
      echo "<li>$cb</li>";
   }
   echo '</ol>';
?>
```

In that case you want to save those checked checkboxes to text file, change php code to this:

```
<?php
   $array = json_decode($_POST['arr'], true);
   $c = 0;
   foreach($array as $cb) {
      file_put_contents('file.txt', $c . '. ' . $cb, FILE_APPEND);
      $c++;
   }
?>
```

Comment: Thanx for your help, I don't have PHP and never worked with PHP so I can't make this code. I want to load the checked checkboxes on a new emty page (ofcourse based on the standard template) of my application I think it can by place the checkboxes in the HTML DIV of my new page, the for output is id="checkboxoutput"